# Using Response Of Function In Another Function

Tags: javascript

```
function tinyurl(){
jQuery.ajax({
url:'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxxxxxx/',
dataType:'script',
success:function(response){
    welcomemsg(response.id);
 }
});
}

 function namie(){
 jQuery.ajax({
 url:'https://xxxxxx.com/names?user=random,
 dataType:'jsonp',
 success:function(data){
 welcomemsg(data);
 }
 });
}

 function welcomemsg(){
 jQuery.ajax({
 url:'https://xxxxx.com/posts?walmessage=Hello ' + data.name + ' your post has been posted '+ response.id +',
 dataType:'script',
 success:function(){
 }
 });
 }
```

Here I am not able to pass response of function tinyurl and response of function namie 
in welcomemsg .

Tried by changing parameter also.

Not getting any success.

I want to use response of tinyurl and namie in function welcomemsg.

Comment: `return yourVariable;`

Comment: please rephrase so that the question and the code make sense.

Comment: will you please tell me in detail ?

Comment: Shouldn't `welcomemsg()` have the parameter `data` in it's definition? Like this: `function welcomemsg(data){`

Comment: @SimonM Tried isnt working

Comment: `welcomemsg` should have two parameters judging from the question.

Comment: Well I'll point this out, AJAX is asynchronous (thats what the "A" is for), so you need to use callback functions in order to access what your AJAX is returning in each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `$.ajax()` function returns a [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object; you can use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to combine both results into one:

```
function tinyurl()
{
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url:'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxxxxxx/',
        dataType:'script'
    });
}

function namie()
{
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url:'https://xxxxxx.com/names?user=random',
        dataType:'jsonp'
    });
}

$.when(tinyurl(), namie()).done(function(a1, a2) {
    var response = a1[0],
    data = a2[0];

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxxx.com/posts?walmessage=Hello ' + data.name + ' your post has been posted '+ response.id,
        dataType:'script',
        success:function(){
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you should use properly escape your URL arguments, i.e.

```
url: 'https://xxxxx.com/posts?' + jQuery.param({
    walmessage: 'Hello ' + data.name + ', your post has been ...'
})
```

Comment: Or use `data: { walmessage: ... }` and jQuery will escape the parameters properly.

Comment: sir will you please elobrate a little :)